# When am I supposed to instantiate Activity class?

Tags: android, android-activity

I see that it is allowed to instantiate `Activity` via `new` keyword.

```
new MainActivity();
```

When I do that, I immediately get access to all its fields, events, etc.

[image]

So, when should I ever need to instantiate some `Activity` class in such a way? I mean in which situations.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Never.  Creating `Activity` instances should always be handled by the `ActivityManager` alone based on the `Intent` items you send.

Comment: I agree 99% of the time. I could see potential uses though. Certain apps have paid and free versions and it is often useful for the code to recognize which version is running and handle logic accordingly. In  these cases though I have still never needed to instantiate an activity to get the package name. Maybe someone else has a legitimate use for instantiating an activity manually?

Comment: Thanks. It's weird I do do not get any warning instantiating the Activity class in such a way.