# Getting MainActivity context in CustomView class

Tags: java, android, android-context, custom-view

I have 2 classes:  MainActivity and CustomView. I have an XML layout with this CustomView.

I want to access all my MainActivity variables from my CustomView class and also to modify them, I tried to get the context but it didn't work.

MainActivity class:

```
 MyCustomView customV;
 int myVar;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.start_page);
    customV = (MyCustomView) findViewById(R.id.view2);
    myVar = 5;
    }
```

MyCustomView class:

```
public class MyCustomView extends TextView {

public MyCustomView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public MyCustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public MyCustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init();
}

context.myVar = 7  //this is what I'm trying to do...
```

I also tried getContext which didn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By trying to access variables from your `Activity` directly in your `TextView` subclass, you introduce tight coupling between you subclass of `Actity` and your custom `TextView`, which essentially hinders the reusability of your custom `TextView` because it can then only be used in that type of `Activity`, using it in another layout would break everything. Basically, I would say it's bad design and would not recommend that approach.

You could simply add a method to your custom `TextView`, and use the variable there :

```
public class MyCustomView extends TextView {

    // your code

    public void setVariable(int myInt){
        //use the int here, either set a member variable 
        //or use directly in the method
    }
}
```

and in your `Activity`

```
customV = (MyCustomView) findViewById(R.id.view2);
customV.setVariable(5);
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer, I understand what you say, But I still don't get what is a better design to my problem. What if myVar is a gridView, and my customView is actually surfaceView. When I draw in surfaceView- I need to know information about the GridView position(in "onTouchEvent" I need something like "context.myVar.pointToPosition(x,y)).  What other ways do I have to get positions of another view if not this design?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, when a touch event happens on GridView, you need to draw something on the SurfaceView ? You could then create a public method in your SurfaceView that you would call in onTouch of your GridView. It's hard to help you without having all the details, but I'd say the main idea is that each View should be independent, and draw/modify itself based  on raw data rather than hold reference to other Views or to the Activity.

Comment: Thanks I'll try that!

Comment: @SHAI see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

or make the variable static and use it like this.

```
 MainActivity.myVar=7;
```

or if you want to initialize in the custom view depend on a variable from the MainActivity  then do it like that in the custom view.

```
private int myVar;
 public void init(int myVar) {
    this.myVar = myVar;
    invalidate();
```

in MainActivity.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.start_page);
customV = (MyCustomView) findViewById(R.id.view2);
myVar = 5;
customV.init(myVar);
}
```

i hope this help you.

Comment: The second solution you propose is essentially the same as mine. The first one, on the other hand, is a **terrible** idea, instantiating an Activity yourself should **never** be done, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10606537/when-am-i-supposed-to-instantiate-activity-class) for details...

Answer (score 1):

Best way to do so is,

```
public class MyCustomView extends TextView {
    private MainActivity mActivity;

    public void setActivity(MainActivity activity) {
        mActivity = activity;
    }

    public MyCustomView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public MyCustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public MyCustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }
}
```

Instantiate,

```
customView = (MyCustomView) findViewById(R.id.view2);
customView.setActivity(this);
```

Access variable inside functions in `MyCustomView`,

```
mActivity.myVar = 10;
```

Comment: Thanks Sazzad, I already tried it but for some reason it didn't work, I couldn't find "my var" in "mActivity". But 2Dee was right, I needed to think about a better design to my project and it solved my problem... Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about the fact that you are tightly coupling your two classes, then the only thing you need to do is typecast your "context" variable to MainActivity.  Something like:

```
((MainActivity) context).myVar = 5;
```

will work.  But you really should consider an alternate design that only loosely couples your classes.

Comment: *If you don't care about [...] tight coupling" --> some people just want to watch the world burn ;-)

Comment: Thanks you are right and your solution really works!  But I used 2Dee solution at the end, thank you.